# Cannot implement shuffle bars feature in sorting algorithm visualizer - setTimeout updates are not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I'm making a sorting algorithm visualizer project and I'm in the process of implementing a shuffle button. The visualization involves bars of different heights getting moved around. I would like the shuffle button to modify the bar array one step at a time, showcasing each swap at a high speed. I've tried tweaking many different things (some of which do move bars around in a strange manner), but I can't seem to get the desired functionality to work. Here's some of the relevant code:

```
// Swap does not modify the original array, but the implementation details don't really affect the result. 
// It basically swaps two elements in the bar array, and then returns the updated array.

    const swapBars = (bars, bar1, bar2) => {
    if (!bars || !bar1 || !bar2) {
      return;
    }
    const _bars = bars;
    let _bar1 = bar1;
    let _bar2 = bar2;

    const tempLeft = _bar1.left;
    _bar1.left = _bar2.left;
    _bar2.left = tempLeft;

    const temp = _bar1;
    _bar1 = _bar2;
    _bar2 = temp;

    return _bars;
  };

// Init bars is basically synchronous shuffle. It takes the array that is created and shuffles it
// because the array should begin in a shuffled state. This is working properly.

  const initBars = (bars) => {
    let currentIndex = bars.length - 1;
    while (currentIndex > 0) {
      // randomIndex will always be different from currentIndex, so each bar will always shuffle
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      swapBars(bars, bars[currentIndex], bars[randomIndex]);
      currentIndex--;
    }
    setBarsToRender(bars);
  };

// createBarArray is what is used to actually populate an empty array with bars depending on a number passed
// through by a slider. This is also working properly.

  const createBarArray = (quantity) => {
    let bars = [];
    const width = calcWidthPercentage(quantity);
    for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
      const height = calcHeightPercentage(quantity, i + 1);
      const left = calcLeftPosPercentage(quantity, i + 1);
      bars.push({ correctPos: i, height: height, width: width, left: left });
    }
    return initBars(bars);
  };

// shuffleBars seems to be broken. I've tried many different things, and this is just the latest snapshot of it.
// It is being called when the shuffle button is being clicked using `shuffleBars(barsToRender)` where barsToRender is the stateful value that is being rendered.

  const shuffleBars = (bars) => {
    let currentIndex = bars.length - 1;
    while (currentIndex > 0) {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setBarsToRender((prev) => {
          return swapBars(prev, prev[currentIndex], prev[randomIndex]);
        });
      }, 50 * (bars.length - currentIndex));
      currentIndex--;
    }
  };
```

If I do something like moving the `swapBars` call inside `setBarsToRender` outside of it and then
do `setBarsToRender[...bars]`, I can see some of the bars moving, but not with the intended behavior (the smallest bar is the only one that keeps swapping). I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding how state updates work inside setTimeout, or if it's something else, so I'd greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the setTimeout and used a `transition delay` to create the staggered effect.

Working demo below:

```js
const swapBars = (bars, bar1, bar2) => {
  if (!bars || !bar1 || !bar2) {
    return;
  }
  const _bars = bars;
  let _bar1 = bar1;
  let _bar2 = bar2;

  const tempLeft = _bar1.left;
  _bar1.left = _bar2.left;
  _bar2.left = tempLeft;

  const temp = _bar1;
  _bar1 = _bar2;
  _bar2 = temp;

  return _bars;
};

const initBars = (bars) => {
  let currentIndex = bars.length - 1;
  while (currentIndex > 0) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    swapBars(bars, bars[currentIndex], bars[randomIndex]);
    currentIndex--;
  }
  return bars;
};

const createBarArray = (quantity) => {
  let bars = [];
  const width = 100 / quantity;
  for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    const height = width * (i + 1);
    const left = width * i;
    bars.push({ correctPos: i, height: height, width: width, left: left });
  }
  return initBars(bars);
};

function Bars({ quantity = 10 }) {
  const [barsToRender, setBarsToRender] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const bars = createBarArray(quantity);

    setBarsToRender(bars);
  }, [quantity]);

  const shuffleBars = () => {
    const bars = [...barsToRender];
    setBarsToRender(initBars(bars));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ul
        style={{
          height: "50vh",
          display: "flex",
          position: "relative"
        }}
      >
        {barsToRender.map((bar, i) => (
          <Bar key={bar.correctPos} bar={bar} index={i} />
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button onClick={shuffleBars}>Shuffle</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Bar({ bar, index: i }) {
  return (
    <li
      style={{
        background: "blue",
        height: `${bar.height}%`,
        width: `${bar.width}%`,
        left: `${bar.left}%`,
        position: "absolute",
        bottom: 0,
        transitionProperty: "left",
        transitionTimingFunction: "ease-in-out",
        transitionDuration: ".25s",
        transitionDelay: `${i*50}ms`
      }}
    >
      <p>{bar.correctPos}</p>
    </li>
  );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<Bars />)
```

```css
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: grid;
  align-content: end;
  justify-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```